# Save_kable() does not save table to PNG file on windows, error on webshot: webshot.js returned failure value 1

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, miktex, webshot

I have a problem with save_kable () in R on windows.  I can not save tables as PNG and pdf.  Returns the message: Error on webshot: webshot returned failure value: 1.

I have Ghostscript, install.packages('magic'),
webshot::install_phantomjs()
library(knitr),
library(kableExtra)